# A problem about the format of section title

Tags: ctex

I want to get the format of the title of each section as shown in the picture below (labeled "**Figure Example_CTeX**"):
[image: Example_CTeX]

This format is from the **Package documentation** ([online PDF](https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/language/chinese/ctex/ctex.pdf)) of **CTeX** and the code corresponding to this format is as follows (noted as `code_ctex`):

```
% use the package "ctex" in standard "article" class or use directly the Chinese-typesetting class "ctexart".

\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}

\ctexset {
  chapter = {
    beforeskip = 0pt,
    fixskip = true,
    format = \Huge\bfseries,
    nameformat = \rule{\linewidth}{1bp}\par\bigskip\hfill\sectionnamebox,
    number = \arabic{chapter},
    aftername = \par\medskip,
    aftertitle = \par\bigskip\nointerlineskip\rule{\linewidth}{2bp}\par
  }
}
\newcommand\sectionnamebox[1]{%
  \parbox{\ccwd}{\linespread{1}\selectfont\centering #1}}

\begin{document}

  \section{熟悉\LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

**PS: I have just replaced the "chapter" with "section" for the sake of simplicity.**

But when I use this code in my latex file, I don't get the format as displayed in above picture. I thus have modified the code above a little bit to get the following new code (noted as `code_moi`):

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}

\ctexset {
  section = {
    beforeskip = 20pt,
    fixskip = true,
    format = \bfseries,
    name   = {第,节},
    nameformat = \rule{\linewidth}{1bp}\par\bigskip\hfill\sectionnamebox,
    number = \arabic{section},
    %aftername = \par\medskip,
    titleformat = \par\medskip\mbox, 
    aftertitle = \par\bigskip\nointerlineskip\rule{\linewidth}{2bp}\par
  } 
}
\newcommand\sectionnamebox[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\ccwd}{\linespread{1}\selectfont\centering #1}}

\begin{document}

\section{导论部分}

\end{document}
```

`code_moi` produces the title format of section as shown in the picture below (labeled "**Figure Example_Moi**"):
[image: Example_Moi]

There is a clear difference between the format produced by `code_moi` and the format shown in "**Figure Example_CTeX**". I would like to know how to adjust the item `nameformat` to get the same effect as the desired format shown in "**Figure Example_CTeX**". Any hints or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `\ctexset{section/hang=false}`.

Initially, `hang=false` for `\part` and `\chapter` (if exist) and `hang=true` for `\section` and lower level sectioning titles. When `hang=true`, the whole title is typeset in an `\hbox`, hence the `\par` in `section/numberformat` has no effect. The doc for `hang` in `texdoc ctex` (v2.5.10, 2022-07-14), sec. 7.3 "间距、缩进相关" has some note about this.

```tex
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}

\ctexset {
  section = {
    hang = false,
    beforeskip = 0pt,
    fixskip = true,
    format = \Huge\bfseries,
    nameformat = \rule{\linewidth}{1bp}\par\bigskip\hfill\sectionnamebox,
    number = \arabic{section},
    aftername = \par\medskip,
    aftertitle = \par\bigskip\nointerlineskip\rule{\linewidth}{2bp}\par
  }
}
\newcommand\sectionnamebox[1]{%
  \parbox{\ccwd}{\linespread{1}\selectfont\centering #1}}

\begin{document}

  \section{熟悉\LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your exceptionally prompt answer! The crucial point about the setting item ```hang = false``` which you have indicated in your answer really helped me a lot. Thank you again with my endless gratitude.

BTW: I have accepted your answer since it solved my problem.